# Cloud function is getting triggred when I am pushing a csv file to bucket but its inserting nulls to bigquery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

```
gsutil notification create -t data-test-notifications -f json gs://vikct001-test-bucket
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create data-test-subscription --topic data-test-notifications
gcloud functions deploy pubsub_to_bigquery --region us-central1 --runtime python37 --trigger-topic data-test-notifications --source gs://pubsub_to_bigquery-bucket/test-code.zip
```

I am having a simple csv file in bucket gs://vikct001-test-bucket and have setup a notifications to pubsub
topic which then needs to be processed via cloud function and insert it into bigquery table.

I was referring to below link for my case study:
https://medium.com/@milosevic81/copy-data-from-pub-sub-to-bigquery-496e003228a1

using below commands to create notification/subscription and to deploy the cloud function.

```
gsutil notification create -t data-test-notifications -f json gs://vikct001-test-bucket
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create data-test-subscription --topic data-test-notifications
gcloud functions deploy pubsub_to_bigquery --region us-central1 --runtime python37 --trigger-topic data-test-notifications --source gs://pubsub_to_bigquery-bucket/test-code.zip
```

Here's my Python code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import base64, json, sys, os


def pubsub_to_bigquery(event, context):

   print("event:",event)
   print("context:",context)
   pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
   incoming_data = json.loads(pubsub_message)
   print("incoming data:",incoming_data)
   write_to_bigquery(os.environ['my_dataset'], os.environ['my_table'], incoming_data)

def write_to_bigquery(dataset, table, document):
   bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
   dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset)
   table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table)
   table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
   errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, [document])
   if errors != [] :
      print(errors, file=sys.stderr)
   else:
      print("New rows have been added to big query table.")
```

Cloud function is getting triggred when I am pushing a csv file to bucket but its inserting nulls to bigquery table.

below is what I have copied from log file.

incoming data: {'kind': 'storage#object', 'id': 'vikct001-test-bucket/input_test_records.csv/1590839144279480', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/vikct001-test-bucket/o/input_test_records.csv', 'name': 'input_test_records.csv', 'bucket': 'vikct001-test-bucket', 'generation': '1590839144279480', 'metageneration': '1', 'contentType': 'text/csv', 'timeCreated': '2020-05-30T11:45:44.279Z', 'updated': '2020-05-30T11:45:44.279Z', 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'timeStorageClassUpdated': '2020-05-30T11:45:44.279Z', 'size': '99', 'md5Hash': '+gsELw4UmqWR/kUZyO2gSg==', 'mediaLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/vikct001-test-bucket/o/input_test_records.csv?generation=1590839144279480&alt=media', 'crc32c': 'zKnBPQ==', 'etag': 'CLjb29DB2+kCEAE='}

Comment: Hi Raghavendra, the medium article tells us about the loading to Pub/Sub data to big query and what you wanted is to transfer data from bucket to csv. You can have a look at this https://medium.com/@asajharland/effective-data-loading-with-bigquery-batch-loading-flat-files-bf2fd0ebb325

Comment: You don't need Pub/Sub for loading the CSV file. Trigger the Cloud Function directly on the bucket and load it, or trigger Dataflow to do the load.

Comment: @Graham Polley. Just a quick question. I have just started learning GCP. so the object metadata has to be in json format then only it can be consumes or matches with pubsub message payload ? it will have nothing in case of object data is in csv or other formats?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you have a file uploaded to GCS and you want that file to be loaded into BigQuery, you have to use Pub/Sub.

Comment: @Graham Polley.. Sorry if I misunderstand the things here. Actually when I was reading the message when csv file was uploaded to bucket was not having metadata in the object. like if we print 'incoming_data' in this case. I can use bucket and object id to load and process the data. I was assuming that there has to be metadata which should contains all the rows.. or data has to be in Json format? I am very new to this so just exploring things here and there. Thanks

Comment: and I was looking for same architecture like my cloud function should trigger when gets notified by pubsub for any csv object being uploaded to my cloud bucket? wht you suggest the efficient way to upload that csv data to bigquery in this case. it has to be like.. bucket-->pubsub-->cloudfunction-->bigquery

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my last comment. I meant to say _"you *don't* have to use Pub/Sub."_ `file -> GCS -> Cloud Function -> BigQuery` or `file -> GCS -> Cloud Function -> Dataflow -> BigQuery`